# MySql 5.7 Server Can't Be Terminated

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I installed MySql 5.7 for work, now I got an active MySql server running on standart port 3306, that I can't terminate.

I tried `service mysql stop` and `service mysqld stop`. No active processes as well.

This is the output of `service mysql status` :

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-11-16 10:09:46 CET; 9min ago
    Process: 65951 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 65990 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 16 10:09:44 user systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Nov 16 10:09:44 user mysqld[65990]: Initialization of mysqld failed: 0
Nov 16 10:09:44 user systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 16 10:09:46 user systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 16 10:09:46 user systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
```

localhost:3006 Response :

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhbku.png)

Output of `journalctl -xe` :

```
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 13189 and the job result is failed.
Nov 16 10:36:40 user systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 37.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Nov 16 10:36:40 user systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 13262 and the job result is done.
Nov 16 10:36:40 user systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 13262.
Nov 16 10:36:40 user audit[71661]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld>
Nov 16 10:36:40 user kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1668591400.604:1307): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile=>
Nov 16 10:36:40 user mysqld[71662]: Initialization of mysqld failed: 0
Nov 16 10:36:40 user systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mysql.service has exited.
```

Comment: Unless I am missing something that status says the server is STOPPED? So now I dont understand the question

Comment: I'm not able to stop the service running on localhost:3306 has it seems to restart or not be terminated in the first place

Comment: And the second log says you cannot start the mysql server, so I am very confused, what cannot be terminated? Or are you missing that it never actually starts and therefore cannot be stopped

Comment: Check the contents of `/var/log/mysql/error.log`. To check for currently running instance `ps -e | grep mysqld`